# Xcode Storyboard Tabbed application (UITabBarController) - tell when tab selected

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller, tabbed-interface

Using Xcode 6 I have created an Tabbed Application using a storyboard with the supplied template.

I need a function to fire when the third tab of the UITabBarController is selected.

I can’t use the ViewDidLoad as I need it fire every time the view is accessed by clicking on the tab (not just the first time( and I can't use ViewWillAppear as I need specific behaviour when view is accessed via the tab as opposed to segued back to from  subsequent (modal) view controllers.

Any advice would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this delegate method of UITabBarControllerDelegate on some UIViewController class

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
NSUInteger indexOfTab = [theTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
// Your code here
    }
```

**OR**

You can subclass UITabBarController and override the following method.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[theTabBar items] indexOfObject:item];
// Your code here}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Where should I implement the function - in the app delegate ?

Comment: @CarlGilbert I have updated my answer for you, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Tried implementing in the app delegate but it is not being called

Comment: have you set its delegate to self?

Comment: If you are having issue with delegate way, Try the second way; simply subclass your tabbarcontroller and override the method in answer.

Comment: thanks for the update, have implemented on one of my UIViewController classes but it is still not being called :-(

Comment: in the viewdid load of any viewcontroller write this: self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

Comment: @CarlGilbert, did my last comment helped?